# How to split array in array and make the length show correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to make the elements that I introduce into variable **flow** from the variable **ll** . Because, in the code below, it's introducing like **array** in **array**. For example:

How do I make it show all 5 elements for any length?

```js
"use strict";

var a1 = [], a2, k, xx;

var floor = function () {
    k = prompt("Elements");
    var flow = k.split(", ");
    console.log(flow);
    var neaha = prompt("New elements");
    var ll = neaha.split(", ");
    console.log(ll);
    flow.push(ll);
    console.log(flow);
    console.log(flow.length);
};

floor();
```

`["1", "2", "3"] + ["4", "5"]` I will get `["1", "2", "3", ["4", "5"] ]` so the length of the array will be 4, but not 5. How to make to show it all 5 elements for any length?

Comment: ["1", "2", "3"]  +

["4", "5"]

I will get ["1", "2", "3", ["4", "5"] ] so the length of the **array** will be 4, but not 5.

How to make to show it all 5 elements for any length?

Comment: Does `console.log(console.log(flow.flat().length));` work?

Comment: @Nick yes, but it is followed by undefined and can I split them, like ONE array, not 2 separated?

Comment: Hmm, I don't quite follow what you're asking. Can you try to rephrase what the problem is?

Comment: @Nick In this example, I get the result like this: ["elements from 1 prompt", ["elements from 2 prompt"] ], but I need the all elements from result of both prompts in one single array, like : ["elements from 1 prompt", "elements from 2 prompt]

Comment: So it still seems `const flatArray =  ["elements from 1 prompt", ["elements from 2 prompt"] ].flat();` would still work. `flatArray` would be the array you're looking for.

Comment: @Nick oh, yeah, perfect, I was searching for this. Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: I will add as an answer if you want to accept it!

Comment: @Nick sure, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flatten an array like this with the `Array.flat` method.

```js
const flatArray = ["elements from 1 prompt", ["elements from 2 prompt"]].flat();

console.log(flatArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `flat()` method to concatenate all the sub array elements:

```
"use strict";
var a1 = [], a2, k, xx;
var floor = function () {
    k = prompt("Elements");
    var flow = k.split(", ");
    console.log(flow);
    var neaha = prompt("New elements");
    var ll = neaha.split(", ")
    console.log(ll);
    flow.push(ll);
    var flow2 = flow.flat();
    console.log(flow2);

    console.log(flow2.length);
};

floor()
```

Comment: I get anyway array in array ["elements from 1 prompt", ["elements from 2 prompt"] ] I need to split them and make the all in one single array. ["elements from 1 prompt", "elements from 2 prompt"]